# Filling between two lines on python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I have the formula below:

```
ax = plt.gca()
datamax.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Data_Value',color='red',ax=ax)
datamin.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Data_Value', color='blue',ax=ax)
plt.ylabel("Temperature (degrees C)",color='navy')
plt.xlabel("Date",color='navy',labelpad=15)
plt.title('Record high and low temperatures by day (2005-2014)', alpha=1.0,color='brown')
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.35),
          fancybox=False,labels=['Record high','Record low'])
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.gca().fill_between(datamax['Date'],datamax['Data_Value'],datamin['Data_Value'],facecolor='yellow',alpha=0.25)
plt.show()
```

I would like to fill between the two lines on the line graph below, but somehow my code is not working. Could anyone help understand why?

I thought that the fill_between command would work but for some reason it is not...

When I try:

```
ax.fill_between(datamax['Date'],datamax['Data_Value'],datamin['Data_Value'],facecolor='yellow',alpha=0.25)
```

I get the error message:

**ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''**

My **graph** currently looks like this:

[image]

The dataframe **datamax** looks like this:

```
 Date           ID Element  Data_Value
0     2005-01-01  USW00094889    TMAX         156
1     2005-01-02  USW00094889    TMAX         139
2     2005-01-03  USW00094889    TMAX         133
3     2005-01-04  USW00094889    TMAX          39
4     2005-01-05  USW00094889    TMAX          33
5     2005-01-06  USW00094889    TMAX           0
6     2005-01-07  USW00094889    TMAX           6
7     2005-01-08  USW00094889    TMAX          17
8     2005-01-09  USW00094889    TMAX          28
9     2005-01-10  USW00094889    TMAX          44
10    2005-01-11  USW00094889    TMAX          44
11    2005-01-12  USW00094889    TMAX         139
12    2005-01-13  USW00094889    TMAX         161
13    2005-01-14  USW00094889    TMAX         150
14    2005-01-15  USW00094889    TMAX         -33
15    2005-01-16  USW00094889    TMAX         -33
16    2005-01-17  USW00094889    TMAX         -50
17    2005-01-18  USW00094889    TMAX         -33
18    2005-01-19  USW00094889    TMAX          11
19    2005-01-20  USW00094889    TMAX          11
20    2005-01-21  USW00094889    TMAX         -39
21    2005-01-22  USW00094889    TMAX         -72
22    2005-01-23  USW00094889    TMAX         -44
23    2005-01-24  USW00094889    TMAX          11
24    2005-01-25  USW00094889    TMAX          28
25    2005-01-26  USW00094889    TMAX          28
26    2005-01-27  USW00094889    TMAX           6
27    2005-01-28  USW00094889    TMAX         -11
28    2005-01-29  USW00094889    TMAX          17
29    2005-01-30  USW00094889    TMAX          28
...          ...          ...     ...         ...
3603  2014-11-13  USW00094889    TMAX          39
3604  2014-11-14  USW00094889    TMAX          33
3605  2014-11-15  USW00094889    TMAX          28
3606  2014-11-16  USW00094889    TMAX          28
3607  2014-11-17  USW00094889    TMAX          17
3608  2014-11-18  USW00094889    TMAX          11
3609  2014-11-19  USW00094889    TMAX          11
3610  2014-11-20  USW00094889    TMAX           6
3611  2014-11-21  USW00094889    TMAX         -10
3612  2014-11-22  USW00094889    TMAX         106
3613  2014-11-23  USW00094889    TMAX         156
3614  2014-11-24  USW00094889    TMAX         172
3615  2014-11-25  USW00094889    TMAX         172
3616  2014-11-26  USW00094889    TMAX          28
3617  2014-11-27  USW00094889    TMAX          39
3618  2014-11-28  USW00094889    TMAX          22
3619  2014-11-29  USW00094889    TMAX         117
3620  2014-11-30  USW00094889    TMAX         178
3621  2014-12-01  USW00094889    TMAX         172
3622  2014-12-02  USW00094889    TMAX          33
3623  2014-12-03  USW00094889    TMAX          61
3624  2014-12-04  USW00094889    TMAX          50
3625  2014-12-05  USW00094889    TMAX          50
3626  2014-12-06  USW00094889    TMAX          67
3627  2014-12-07  USW00094889    TMAX          67
3628  2014-12-08  USW00094889    TMAX          72
3629  2014-12-09  USW00094889    TMAX          56
3630  2014-12-10  USW00094889    TMAX          50
3631  2014-12-11  USW00094889    TMAX          61
3632  2014-12-12  USW00094889    TMAX          50

[3631 rows x 4 columns]
```

And the dataframe **datamin** like this:

```
 Date           ID Element  Data_Value
0     2005-01-01  USC00200032    TMIN         -56
1     2005-01-02  USC00200032    TMIN         -56
2     2005-01-03  USC00200032    TMIN           0
3     2005-01-04  USC00200032    TMIN         -39
4     2005-01-05  USC00200032    TMIN         -94
5     2005-01-06  USC00200032    TMIN        -106
6     2005-01-07  USC00200032    TMIN        -111
7     2005-01-08  USC00200032    TMIN        -100
8     2005-01-09  USC00200032    TMIN         -67
9     2005-01-10  USC00200032    TMIN         -56
10    2005-01-11  USC00200032    TMIN         -22
11    2005-01-12  USC00200032    TMIN         -17
12    2005-01-13  USC00200032    TMIN         -83
13    2005-01-14  USC00200032    TMIN        -128
14    2005-01-15  USC00200032    TMIN        -144
15    2005-01-16  USC00200032    TMIN        -150
16    2005-01-17  USC00200032    TMIN        -189
17    2005-01-18  USC00200032    TMIN        -217
18    2005-01-19  USC00200228    TMIN        -300
19    2005-01-20  USC00200032    TMIN        -156
20    2005-01-21  USC00200032    TMIN        -178
21    2005-01-22  USC00200032    TMIN        -178
22    2005-01-23  USC00200032    TMIN        -250
23    2005-01-24  USC00200032    TMIN        -267
24    2005-01-25  USC00200032    TMIN        -228
25    2005-01-26  USC00200032    TMIN        -206
26    2005-01-27  USC00200032    TMIN        -239
27    2005-01-28  USC00200032    TMIN        -250
28    2005-01-29  USC00200032    TMIN        -222
29    2005-01-30  USC00200228    TMIN        -217
...          ...          ...     ...         ...
3603  2014-11-13  USC00200032    TMIN         -71
3604  2014-11-14  USC00200032    TMIN         -78
3605  2014-11-15  USC00200032    TMIN         -94
3606  2014-11-16  USC00200032    TMIN         -72
3607  2014-11-17  USC00200032    TMIN        -106
3608  2014-11-18  USC00200032    TMIN        -144
3609  2014-11-19  USC00200032    TMIN        -128
3610  2014-11-20  USC00200032    TMIN        -122
3611  2014-11-21  USC00200032    TMIN        -182
3612  2014-11-22  USC00200032    TMIN        -172
3613  2014-11-23  USC00200032    TMIN        -100
3614  2014-11-24  USC00200032    TMIN          -5
3615  2014-11-25  USC00200032    TMIN         -33
3616  2014-11-26  USC00200032    TMIN         -67
3617  2014-11-27  USC00200032    TMIN         -82
3618  2014-11-28  USC00200032    TMIN        -133
3619  2014-11-29  USC00200032    TMIN        -106
3620  2014-11-30  USC00200032    TMIN         -56
3621  2014-12-01  USC00200032    TMIN         -88
3622  2014-12-02  USC00200032    TMIN         -99
3623  2014-12-03  USC00200032    TMIN         -71
3624  2014-12-04  USC00200032    TMIN         -77
3625  2014-12-05  USC00200032    TMIN         -61
3626  2014-12-06  USC00200032    TMIN         -50
3627  2014-12-07  USC00200032    TMIN         -78
3628  2014-12-08  USC00200032    TMIN         -78
3629  2014-12-09  USC00200032    TMIN         -39
3630  2014-12-10  USC00200032    TMIN         -72
3631  2014-12-11  USC00200032    TMIN         -88
3632  2014-12-12  USC00200032    TMIN         -78

[3631 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Try not mixing pandas plotting and direct calls to matplotlib methods. In this case, I would stick to bare matplotlib as pandas does some clever, but different things with dates than raw matplotlib would. Always act on the axes explicitly (i.e., `ax.fill_between`, not `plt.gca().fill_between`)

Comment: @PaulH please see my edit above!

Comment: looks like you've got some bad data in your dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PaulH what do you mean bad data?

Comment: I mean you have some data that numpy is having trouble properly treating as necessary for the matplotlib's plotting methods. So post an MRE that demonstrates that error with 10 - 20 lines of the dataset. I bet that in creating the example, you'll solve your own problem before you even come back here.

Comment: if i had to guess, you've got some null values

Comment: @PaulH see answer below1

Comment: What do you want me to do with that?

Comment: @PaulH nothing, just celebrate with me that I managed to figure out the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Python code which returns a line graph of the record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014. The area between the record high and record low temperatures for each day should be shaded.
2. Then, overlay a scatter of the 2015 data for any points (highs and lows) for which the ten year record (2005-2014) record high or record low was broken in 2015.
3. Remove leap year dates (i.e. 29th February).

/

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option("display.max_rows",None,"display.max_columns",None)
data = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv') 
newdata = data[(data['Date'] >= '2005-01-01') & (data['Date'] <= '2014-12-12')]
datamax = newdata[newdata['Element']=='TMAX']
datamin = newdata[newdata['Element']=='TMIN']
datamax['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamax['Date'])
datamin['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamin['Date'])
datamax["day_of_year"] = datamax["Date"].dt.dayofyear
datamax = datamax.groupby('day_of_year').max()
datamin["day_of_year"] = datamin["Date"].dt.dayofyear
datamin = datamin.groupby('day_of_year').min()
datamax = datamax.reset_index()
datamin = datamin.reset_index()
datamin['Date'] = datamin['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
datamax['Date'] = datamax['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
datamax = datamax[~datamax['Date'].str.contains("02-29")]
datamin = datamin[~datamin['Date'].str.contains("02-29")]

breakoutdata = data[(data['Date']  > '2014-12-31')]
datamax2015 = breakoutdata[breakoutdata['Element']=='TMAX']
datamin2015 = breakoutdata[breakoutdata['Element']=='TMIN']
datamax2015['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamax2015['Date'])
datamin2015['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamin2015['Date'])
datamax2015["day_of_year"] = datamax2015["Date"].dt.dayofyear
datamax2015 = datamax2015.groupby('day_of_year').max()
datamin2015["day_of_year"] = datamin2015["Date"].dt.dayofyear
datamin2015 = datamin2015.groupby('day_of_year').min()
datamax2015 = datamax2015.reset_index()
datamin2015 = datamin2015.reset_index()
datamin2015['Date'] = datamin2015['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
datamax2015['Date'] = datamax2015['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
datamax2015 = datamax2015[~datamax2015['Date'].str.contains("02-29")]
datamin2015 = datamin2015[~datamin2015['Date'].str.contains("02-29")]

dataminappend = datamin2015.join(datamin,on="day_of_year",rsuffix="_new")
lower = dataminappend.loc[dataminappend["Data_Value_new"]>dataminappend["Data_Value"]]
datamaxappend = datamax2015.join(datamax,on="day_of_year",rsuffix="_new")
upper = datamaxappend.loc[datamaxappend["Data_Value_new"]<datamaxappend["Data_Value"]]

upper['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(upper['Date']) 
lower['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(lower['Date']) 
datamax['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamax['Date']) 
datamin['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamin['Date']) 

ax = plt.gca()
plt.plot(datamax['day_of_year'],datamax['Data_Value'],color='red')
plt.plot(datamin['day_of_year'],datamin['Data_Value'], color='blue')
plt.scatter(upper['day_of_year'],upper['Data_Value'],color='purple')
plt.scatter(lower['day_of_year'],lower['Data_Value'], color='cyan')

plt.ylabel("Temperature (degrees C)",color='navy')
plt.xlabel("Day of the year",color='navy',labelpad=15)
plt.title('Record high and low temperatures by day between 2005-2014)', alpha=1.0,color='brown',y=1.08)
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.35),fancybox=False,labels=['Record high','Record low'])
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.fill_between(range(len(datamax['Date'])), datamax['Data_Value'], datamin['Data_Value'],color='yellow',alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

/

4. I have converted the 'Date' column to a string using Datamin['Date'] = datamin['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').
5. I have then converted this back to 'datetime' format using upper['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(upper['Date'])
6. I then used 'date of year' as the x-value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```py
plt.fill_between(datamax['Date'],datamax['Data_Value'],datamin['Data_Value'],facecolor='yellow',alpha=0.25)
```

Instead of

```py
plt.gca().fill_between(datamax['Date'],datamax['Data_Value'],datamin['Data_Value'],facecolor='yellow',alpha=0.25)
```

Comment: one should use `ax.fill_between` before `plt.fill_between`, which calls, `plt.gca().fill_between` under the hood.

Comment: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @sam this is the error message I am getting. What do you think is wrong with my data?

Comment: That seems to be related to dtype of the series in the datagram. Can you change the type to float/int64 if it is not that?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2014-12-12'

Comment: when I tried: datamax = datamax['Date'].astype(float)
datamin = datamin['Date'].astype(float)

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2005-01-01' for int64

Comment: my x-axis values are in the form "Datetime"

Comment: Not the date, you should make the y value as float/int64. Date can be as it is

Comment: @sam, yes when I do it for the Y value, I still get the error ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @sam see answer below1